# how to proxy API requests? (Angular-CLI)

Tags: spring, angular, spring-security, angular5

I'm working on Java project with Spring-4 and Angular-5. Session is generated on spring side.

So, I'm not able to generate this session from angular Service. It's working on Postman and I'm able to get response in PostMan. 
But It's not working with Angular post method call.

So, I thought that it's may be a issue of Proxy. (Corrent me If i'm wrong).

So, My local Url is :- http://localhost:8080/MacromWeb/ws/login
So, How Can I make a `proxy.conf.json` file?

So for that I have added this code to my `package.json` file,

```
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
```

I have created a new file called `proxy.conf.json`.
And Put this code in it.

```
{
  "/": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080/MacromWeb/ws",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

Then I tried with `ng serve` and `npm start` both.

Postman Screenshot. 
[image]

Comment: And when you make the http call what endpoint do you use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this through proxy, You need to provide proper values in the proxy config.

`/*` should work too, but if `MacromWeb` is common in API URLs, then instead of `/` provide `/MacromWeb/*`

`proxy.conf.json` looks something like this,

```
{
    "/MacromWeb/*": {
        "target": {
            "host": "localhost",
            "protocol": "http:",
            "port": 8080
        },
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ohk. Thank you for the quick answer. Is this code for `proxy.conf.json` ?

Comment: Yes, This is `proxy.conf.json` , Although I would suggest you to use javascript file `proxy.conf.js`, if the application API calls are made to different API endpoints (or different servers)

Comment: I have tried your code brother. It's not working. I have to change any thing to `package.json` ? I have a question that I'm using this service from this url `http://localhost:4200/#/pages/login` and I'm calling this url `http://localhost:8080/MacromWeb/ws/login`. So is it works ?

Comment: @Bhavin, You shouldnt explicitly use the whole URL like this -> `http://localhost:8080/MacromWeb/ws/login` while making API call, You should use something like this ->   `this.http.get("MacromWeb/ws/login")`

Comment: Base path also matters in this, what is the base path you are using in `index.html`?

Comment: Base path is:-  `<base href="./">`

Comment: Yeah. I'm using url like this `this.http.get("MacromWeb/ws/login")` while calling webservice url.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171312/discussion-between-basavaraj-bhusani-and-bhavin).

Answer (score 0):

Say we have a server running on http://localhost:3000 and we want all calls to http://localhost:4200/api to go to that server.

In our proxy.conf.json file, we add the following content

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""
    }
  }
}
```

More on this: [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md)